# animate non defined movements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'll go straight to the point: when hovering on a div I set the javascript to display a hidden div. This makes the hovered one move...
It is a very sudden movement and I'd like to animate it but since I never told the div to move I cannot understand (I'm a pure beginner) how to define it (I'd like to see a soft movement to the top).

I add the code

```
   <div class='modal'>

  <div class='content'>
    <div class="row" style="padding: 15px;">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropbtn"><a class="work">Works</a></div>
        <div class="row inside-link">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4"> <a href="portofolio/video/video.html">Video</a></div>

            <div class="col-4"> <a href="portofolio/photography/photography.html">Photo</a></div>
            <div class="col-4"> <a href="portofolio/graphics/graphics.html">Graphics</a></div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row"><a href="about.html">About</a></div>
    <div class="row"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></div>
```

which is animated by the following javascript code

```
    <script>
  $(function() {
    $(".dropdown").hover(function() {
      $(".row.inside-link").fadeIn();
    }, function() {
      $(".row.inside-link").fadeOut();
    });
  });

</script>
```

What I'd like to see is "works" move smoothly before that ".row.inside link" is shown (in css it is "display:none"). Since I only defined the movement done by ".row.inside link" I'm not understanding how to do that. 
I suceed in having a movement of the whole block but it wasn't what I what.

Thanks to who will help me with that.
Cheers
Francesco

Comment: Why don't you use pure CSS? CSS3 animations are better to that kind of stuff.

Comment: HI D. Pardal! Thanks for your answer!I tried to use only CSS but seemed to not work properly. But maybe I didn't managed the code well!

Comment: You're welcome anyway! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='modal'>

        <div class='content'>
            <div class="row" style="padding: 15px;">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <div class="dropbtn">
                        <a class="work">Works</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row inside-link">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <a href="portofolio/video/video.html">Video</a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-4">
                                <a href="portofolio/photography/photography.html">Photo</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <a href="portofolio/graphics/graphics.html">Graphics</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </div>

            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $(".row.inside-link").hide();
                    $(".dropdown").hover(function () {
                        $(".row.inside-link").slideDown();
                    }, function () {
                        $(".row.inside-link").slideUp();
                    });
                });

            </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Vu Huu, 
thank you very much this event is definitely very close to what I wanted to obtain!! :)